# jQuery - Calendar plugin, pre selected dates on multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using a calendar plugin for jQuery, im using the 'selecting multiple dates' demo which is here http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiple.html

Im using the demo code for starters which is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function()
{
    $('.date-pick')
        .datePicker(
            {
                createButton:false,
                displayClose:true,
                closeOnSelect:false,
                selectMultiple:true
            }
        )
        .bind(
            'click',
            function()
            {
                $(this).dpDisplay();
                this.blur();
                return false;
            }
        )
        .bind(
            'dateSelected',
            function(e, selectedDate, $td, state)
            {
                console.log('You ' + (state ? '' : 'un') // wrap
                    + 'selected ' + selectedDate);

            }
        )
        .bind(
            'dpClosed',
            function(e, selectedDates)
            {
                console.log('You closed the date picker and the ' // wrap
                    + 'currently selected dates are:');
                console.log(selectedDates);
            }
        );
});
</script>
```

This works great, i want to be able to pre select dates somehow, im getting dates from the database, and i want to be able to show them as checked when i click the link to open the calendar.

If anyone has any experience with this, i would love some help ... im not a jQuery nut at all, so its hard to figure this out.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `dpSetSelected` method to set the dates you need, one at a time

Whatever code you use to get the list of dates from the database, run loop over them

```
var arrDates = ['01/01/2010', '01/05/2010', '01/10/2010'];
var dp = $('.date-picker');
for(var i = 0; i < arrDates.length; i++){
    dp.dpSetSelected(arrDates[i]);
}
```

Comment: I have tried that one, the dpSetSelected method selects the date on which the calendar should start, not which dates are pre highlighted

Comment: @cecil It works for me... Note 1) setSelected take a date format of `DD/MM/YYYY` and 2) the date must be in the date range allowed.

Comment: Hmmm .. Interesting, it is working, but only for 1 of the dates ( the first one ) in the array -var arrDates = ['19/01/2011', '20/01/2011', '21/01/2011'];

Comment: Ok ... I managed to figure it out by chopping and pasting code everywhere, seems to work hahaha